# How to check if text field conains 6 digits

Tags: excel, filter, numbers

I was wondering how one would go about filtering a set of column data e.g.
BLK 123 123456
BLK 123

Basically I want to display BLK 123 123456

Any idea how i would go about doing that? Ive tried Filter Custom Filters to set more than 100000, but it wouldn't work as its a text field.

Any help?

Comment: Can you give more information what you're trying to do?  Your column data is BLK 123 123456 BLK 123?  is it relevent that it repeats?  You want to display up until you find a string of 6 digits?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make some kind of regular expression, correct?

So, the answer involves something along the lines of [0-9]{6}, or \d{6} if you prefer...

Comment: Hi, tried this in excel doesn't work (Placed [0-9]{6} in Custom Filters, Contains, for field BLK 123 123456

Comment: Is the format fixed ie. if there is definite lenght of data. Havr you tried mid()?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will check cell A1 for a match.

```
=MATCH(TRUE,VALUE(MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},6))>99999)
```

It works by grabbing 6 characters at a time, each starting at index 1...20, converts all of them to values, then to Boolean true if the value is >= 99999, then searches for TRUE.  If a match is found your string has 6 digits (somewhere in the first 26 characters).

From the title of your question I believe this was what you're asking.  From the body of your question, I suppose the application of this solution would have to be the formula in another column.